# How do I add a string to the index?

Tags: jquery

I understand that if we use 'index', it starts from the 0 element.

I suppose the script below renames the 'name' attribute starting from "ao1". How do I write the script in a way where it starts renaming from "ao2" onwards?

```
$("div.searchtextdiv p .andor").each(function(index)  {
     $(this).attr("name","ao" + ++index);
});
```

Comment: you should use `(` for concat string with int `"ao"+ (++index)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("div.searchtextdiv p .andor").each(function(index)  {
     $(this).attr("name","ao" + (index + 2));
});
```

this can be even simplified using [attr setter](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) which takes a function as argument

```
$("div.searchtextdiv p .andor").attr('name', function (index) {
    return "ao" + (index + 2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not add string to the index, its better to keep numeric indexed in jQuery.

Instead you can add attribute to the element like `data-myindex="number+string"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming index = 0,

"ao" + index+1 gives result `ao01` //index + 1 ==> string is appended

whereas

"ao" + (index+1) gives result `ao1` //(index+1) ==> integer is appended

Try:

```
$("div.searchtextdiv p .andor").each(function(index)  {
     $(this).attr("name","ao" + (index+1));
});
```